# Java sockets closing HTTP 1.0 connections

Tags: java, http, parsing, sockets, webserver

I'm writing a small web server, and having a problem with parsing a request.  I parse a BufferedReader into a LinkedList (so that I can perform operation based on POST data sent.)  I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577719/java-sockets-bufferedreader-and-readline-hang) explaining that the buffer isn't terminated due to the connection hanging open.  I'm not sure how to close it.

How I open the socket (and how I thought to close it):

```
            Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            InetAddress client = connectionSocket.getInetAddress();

            System.out.println(client.getHostName() + " connected to server.");

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

            output.writeUTF(httpHeader(200));

            httpHandler(input, output);

            connectionSocket.close();
```

The httpHeader method forms a simple string with "HTTP/1.0" on the first line, and in this case, "200 OK" on the next line and a new line at the end.  The POST request that is sent is HTTP 1.0.

Being as concise as I could manage, my question is two-fold: How do I properly respond to and close a HTTP 1.0 POST request/socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A POST request has associated data, and MUST be accompanied by a Content-Length header specifying the exact length of that POST data.

So, you must first real all HTTP headers, decode the Content-Length, and then read the POST data (which is, as is classical with HTTP, separated from the headers by an empty line).

If the amount of data is not sufficient, *or* there is too much of it, *or* you don't even receive a Content-Length header, then you should return 400.