# Java program freezes after BufferedReader While loop in Socket

Tags: java, sockets

```
    Socket s;
    try {
        s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com"), 80);

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        pw.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
        pw.println("Host: stackoverflow.com");
        pw.println();
        pw.flush();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        String t;

        while((t = br.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(t);

        br.close(); 

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I think the problem in the While loop but i don't know how to stop it after fetching all data.

Comment: You will need to read the header in the response and find the content length, then read that many bytes, then close the socket. The connection is probably being kept alive and is waiting for you to send another request. Why not use HttpClient to do this instead? http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1577833/4028581

> Your problem is the content encoding “chunked”. This is used when the length of the content requested from the web server is not known at the time the response is started. It basically consists of the number of bytes being sent, followed by CRLF, followed by the bytes. The end of a response is signalled by the exact sequence you are seeing. The web server is now waiting for your next request (this is also called “request pipelining”).
>
> You have several possibilities:
>
> 1- Use HTTP version 1.0. This will cause the webserver to automatically close the connection when a response has been sent completely.
>
> 2- Specify the “Connection: close” header when sending your request. This will also close the connection.
>
> 3- Parse content encoding “chunked” correctly and simply treat this as if the response is now complete—which it is.
>
> By: Bombe